# Wirtinger Derivate

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question regarding the solution of the following problem:

> Let $D\subseteq\mathbb C$ and $\overline D:=\{z\in\mathbb C:\overline z\in D\}$. Show that $f:D\to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic iff $g(z):=\overline{f(\overline{z})}:\ \overline D\to\mathbb C$ is holomorphic.

Proof.

Let $z,a\in\overline D$. Then

[image]

so the complex derivate of $g(z)$ in $a\in\overline D$ exists iff the complex derivate of $f$ in $\overline a$ exists.

My question regards the last line in the equation: If we pull the complex conjugation above everything shouldn't we get the limit $$\lim_{\overline{z}\to\overline{a}}\cdots$$
Otherwise I don't understand how the last limit is the derivate of $f$ in $\bar a$.

Comment: If $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$, then $(\overline{z_n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $\overline{a}$. Therefore $\lim_{z\to a}$ is the same as $\lim_{\overline{z}\to\overline{a}}$.

Comment: Recall that $z,a \in \overline{D}$ and that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$, thus it has to be $\lim \limits_{z \to a} \dots$ instead of $\lim \limits_{\overline{z} \to \overline{a}} \dots$

Comment: @Nightgap That sounds reasonable! Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the source of this problem?